# Tera Term の ttmacro でキーファイルで接続パスは相対パス指定できますか？

Tags: teraterm

現在TTLmacroは接続先用の鍵を指定しますが、相対パス指定できますか？

できるはずと思い色々試していますが、全ケース下記のメッセージ発生し、相対パス指定できる？

```
---------------------------
TTSSH
---------------------------
SSH2秘密鍵の読み込みに失敗しました
No such file or directory
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

色々な相対パスのベースディレクトリ試した。

1. ttmacro はWindowsのshortcutで実行したので、シートカットのWorking Directoryはベースパス試して、NG
2. マクロファイルの位置ディレクトリは相対ベースパスも試して、NG

Comment: 「TTLmacro」でweb検索すると [ttlmacro.exeの引数は絶対パスで！](https://www.banana-juice.com/tech/articles/20120815) というページが見つかりました。 / これでも解決しない場合には、実際に利用しているマクロファイルの内容や実行時のコマンドなども質問に含めると具体的なアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: @cubick 結局絶対パスだけ可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

基本的には無理だと思ってください。

マクロのconnectコマンドのパラメータで鍵ファイル等が指定できますが、このパラメータを実際に評価するのはマクロでは無く、(新しく起動された)Tera Term本体が行います。
そしてTera Termは起動した時にDLL Injection攻撃を防ぐ為にカレントディレクトリをTera Termがインストールされているディレクトリに変更します。
その為、鍵ファイルを相対パスで指定した場合は Tera Term のインストールディレクトリからの相対パスとして処理が行われます。

なので Tera Term のインストールディレクトリからの相対パスで指定すれば使えますが、これは期待した指定の仕方ではないでしょう。なので、相対パスでの指定は無理だと思ってください。

Comment: 相対パスのベースはTeraterm起動ディレクトリ確認できて、相対パス意味がないですね。